# Platform Event ReplayId - metadata says it is a String of length 1000 but evidence shows it as an integer

Tags: platform-event

[Related post on uniqueness of replayIds](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215448/is-replayid-system-field-of-platfom-event-unique)

Using Workbench to examine metadata for the OOTB field `ReplayId` on any Platform Event SObject (one that ends in `__e`) shows:

- bytelength: 3000
- length: 1000
- type: String

Now, evidence shows (and [Platform Event documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_define_ui.htm) and related [StreamingAPI documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_durability.htm?search_text=replayid)) this value to be an integer. Even the JSON example in the StreamingAPI shows it as a number:

```
{
 "clientId":"a1ps4wpe52qytvcvbsko09tapc",
 "data":{
    "event":{
            "createdDate":"2016-03-29T19:05:28.334Z",
            "replayId":55
        },
    "payload":"This is a message."
    },
 "channel":"/u/TestStreaming"
}
```

Further cementing the evidence that Replayid is an integer, doing a metadata describe on `EventBusSubcriber`, the fields `Tip` and `Position` are both of type `int` with 9 digit precision.  These two fields define the relative points in the stream between last event published versus last event consumed.

> So, should I care? Or is an assumption of integers good enough?

**Rationale for asking ...**
I was planning on a solution wherein I backed up incoming platform events to Sobjects by publishing out another platform event (which is guaranteed to publish even if the initial consuming transaction blows up on a Limits exception).  Think of this a fallback backup solution.

The backup SObject had a uniquekey defined as the concatenation of the initial xxx__e sobjectType + Replayid.  This strategy works fine if replayids are numbers as the unique key will be < 255 chars in length. But if Replayids can be 1000 characters long, I need to rethink things.

*Side note ..to date in our org, Replayids have incremented up to about 1,000,000 for the most active xxx__e platform events*

Answer (score 3):

> So, should I care? Or is an assumption of integers good enough?

In my opinion, as long as it's documented to be *numeric*, I would go ahead and utilize this as *number*.

While this is still not clear why the describe would show a different result, but in any case if there's a scenario where there seems to be a discrepancy, I would reach out to Salesforce to make sure the implementation based on documentation will not fail.

Thinking it from a different perspective, if I use a Java Client using *CometD* to subscribe to an Event, I will always pass an *numeric replayId* instead of a String value to make sure that I successfully retrieve all replay ids after the value that I am passing.

Comment: Jayant -- The CometD evidence was pretty convincing to me to stick with current plan; will let this marinate a bit to see what other responses come through.

Comment: I am still baffled why does the describe on the field show it as string (I verified it myself). Will see if I can reach out to Salesforce support.

Comment: @JayantDas Yes, I'd suggest contacting support. Bugs like this have happened before, and they usually get it fixed.